# Time taken for journey to the moon

Tags: moonlanding

[image]

India is going to launch a spacecraft to the moon on 16 July which will consist of a lander, an orbiter and a rover. I found an article in today's newspaper regarding   this. If you zoom in a bit, you will be able to see the list of other lunar missions that have taken place over the years. A common difference that I found in lunar missions of 20th century and lunar missions of 21st century was the time. Earlier, the spacecrafts reached moon in a day or two but recent missions take over 2 months.

With developed technology, it should take even less time, but it's the other way round. Can anyone explain the reason behind this.

Comment: Welcome! This is more of a [space.se] question than an Astronomy one.

Comment: Times of India [article online](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/why-the-world-keeps-returning-to-chandamama/articleshow/70033479.cms)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Astronomy as defined in the [help center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I would recommend that you ask in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) except that you have already [posted the question there](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37083/12102) as well and hopefully it will be re-opened soon. For future reference, cross-posting the same question in multiple SE sites is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @uhoh I initially posted the question here as I didn't know that there was a stack exchange site specifically for space exploration. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Sure, Stack Exchange runs a bit differently than most other Q&A sites, it takes a while to get used to its idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some trajectories need less energy than others, so to save on fuel, scientists often choose the lengthy, fuel efficient journey rather than a shorter one. In the case of the Apollo astronauts, it was important to get them to the moon in the shortest possible time, so a short trajectory was chosen.